# android animating/scale up children in gridview gets clipped by the container gridview gives

Tags: android, animation, gridview

I have a grid view of collection of a custom view. The custom view is a framelayout with two imageview overlapped on top of each other. The imageview are of the same size. When i animate or scale up the custom view, it is clipped by the bounds the gridview gives each child. I have already set clipchildren to false on the gridview but problem still persists. What is the work around?